# Visual model of coordinated system in Python

Tags: python, imaging, python-imaging-library

I have some output which reads like:

```
(x0, y0, z0) : (x1, y1, z1)
```

The data represents spacial transformations. I would very much appreciate any sort of method which will visually map that data to an image or animation. The idea is to help myself better understand Riemann space. Ultimately I would like to show a comparison using a visual representation of `tuple(a)` mapped to `tuple(b)`, then `tuple(b)` mapped to `tuple(a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to visualize Riemann zeta functions in 3d space, and you specifically want to do it in python, you should look at this blog post: http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/wordpress/?p=1079

It uses [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) for the math and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) for visualization.  It contains some sample youtube videos, and [source code](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/zeta_3dplot.py) is linked at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about Complex analysis this is not an elementary graphics task. If you want to really illustrate your transformation you're gonna need to show your whole space warping, your coordinate lines bending (but staying perpendicular!), and a whole mess of other tasks.

I found this site with some animations:
http://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold/complex-maps/

It says they were made in Mathematica. Maybe try there? I don't know if Python is what you're looking for.